# SQL Union/Join Query

Tags: sql, join, db2, union

I have a user profile table with columns `User Name`, `Manager` and many other fields, for example, `Amount`.

Example  Records:

```
User    Manager  Amount
A       B       100
x       y       200
B       C       300
M       N       800
C       D       500
P       Q       1000
D       E       1000
```

I am trying to get the result as below:

```
User    Manager Amount
A       B       100
B       C       300
C       D       500
D       E       1000
```

Basically, I just want to show the results in cascading manner so that all the rows are fetched until it finds all managers in the hierarchy for a user. Can somebody help?

============

**Update**

I managed to solve the problem using the below query:

```
WITH rec(c1, c2)
AS (SELECT c1, c2 FROM table WHERE c2 = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT table.c1, table.c2 FROM table, rec WHERE table.c2 = rec.c2)
SELECT c1, c2 FROM rec
```

Thanks for the help.
Abhi.

Comment: Could you expand on whether a user might have multiple managers, and whether a manager can have multiple users, and what you'd need in those instances? Or are you always restricting your query to one user as the starting point?

Comment: One user can have only one manager, but one manager can be manager of more than one users.
My starting point will be user A and I want to list down all the managers in the heirarchy.

Comment: @Abhi: Please add your solution as an answer, so others can more easily find it in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no "standard" sql for doing that, However most databases extend SQL to have these options.

In Oracle you can do something like:

```
SELECT USER, Manager, Amount FROM employees CONNECT BY PRIOR USER = Manager;
```

please see some examples in:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0510rielau/
for db2 examples

Comment: Hi Guy,
Connect By clause doesn't work in DB2/400, but you have shown me the path. I will try to find if there is an alternative to Connect By clause in DB2/400.
Thanks.